# How to display images without their titles in Drupal 8?

Tags: image, drupal-8

Drupal 8.5.3

I want to display some images in a Views Block in a grid format and without the image title being shown. This is not working and the title is always displayed.

1. I have created a content type for the images with just the required title field and the image field and I have deleted the body field.
2. I have set the image label to hidden or "visually hidden" in the content view mode in the "Manage Display" tab for both default and teaser. The label seems to affect only the name of the content type itself not the image title.
3. I have set the view grid to display only teasers.
4. I have run drush cr multiple times.

The image titles still show up in the view.I can find no way to turn them off there. However the tile is not displayed in the default view mode on the node page itself. Which ironically is where I want it!

Comment: Please can you provide the code showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do exclude node tiles from display. You have to use a contrib module such as the appropriately named [Exclude Node Title](http://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal media types such as image also have a field_image type that has it's own label or title. This can be set to visually hidden (accessible to screen readers and seo) or hidden (set to display none or simply not output - not s great for screen readers). If using an entity reference to this, this also has it's own label/title.

Additionally an image can have it's own alt and title attributes.